# How do I create an (r,c,n) array by performing a function on each element of an (r,c) dataframe? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This issue is part of a data visualization. Each element of an (r,c) dataframe has a value between 0 and 1 (or NaN) and I'm using that number to calculate each element's corresponding RGB value. These go into an (r,c,3) array, where the "3" is where the red, green and blue values are stored. This array is used by matplotlib's `imshow` to create my visualization. The RGB calculation is somewhat complex, requiring an if-elif that depends on the column of the data frame that the element is in.

As an example, I start with the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.0,0.4,1.0],'b':[0.25,np.float('NaN'),0.75],'c':[0.25,0.6,0.75]})
print(df)
     a     b     c
0  0.0  0.25  0.25
1  0.4   NaN  0.60
2  1.0  0.75  0.75
```

Currently I use the following code, which works, but it just doesn't seem Pythonic:

```
column_list_1 = ['a','b'] # these columns get colored differently
rgb = np.zeros((df.shape[0], df.shape[1], 3)) #Prepares array, defaults to (0,0,0) (black) for NaNs
for i in range(df.shape[0]): #Non-Pythonic nested for loop through two dimension
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        if (~np.isnan(df.iloc[i,j])) and (df.columns[j] in column_list_1): #for these columns 0:green, .5:yellow, 1:red
            rgb[i][j] = [min(2*df.iloc[i,j],1), min(2-2*df.iloc[i,j],1), 0] #fancy math to map [0,1] to [green-yellow-red]
        elif (~np.isnan(df.iloc[i,j])): #for remaining columns 0:red, 0.5:yellow, 1:green
            rgb[i][j] = [min(2-2*df.iloc[i,j],1), min(2*df.iloc[i,j],1), 0]
print(rgb)
[[[0.  1.  0. ]
  [0.5 1.  0. ]
  [1.  0.5 0. ]]

 [[0.8 1.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.8 1.  0. ]]

 [[1.  0.  0. ]
  [1.  0.5 0. ]
  [0.5 1.  0. ]]]
plt.imshow(rgb)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.imshow(rgb)
ax.set_xticks([0,1,2])
ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns)
```

[image]

I feel like there must be a better way of creating the array I need for `imshow` from the dataframe. I would really like that question answered for my own edification, but I'll also accept other suggestions about how I could have accomplished what I was trying to do.

Edit: I think it's clear that a heatmap is what I should have been using to create my data visualization. However, I'm still interested in learning the answer to the question in my title- how to create an (r,c,n) array by performing a function on each element of an (r,c) dataframe *without* a nested loop through the rows and columns.

Comment: Are you sure pandas is the right tool here? Vs for example, numpy arrays?

Comment: Could you try to re-explain your objective? I couldn't understand it.

Comment: The seaborn heatmap might be of interest to you https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Comment: Alexander- I've been working with a dataframe for a project. I used this to create new columns of scores between 0 and 1, and I'd like to display those scores visually. (For my example, I'm just taking those new score columns and treating them as their own dataframe.) I came across matplotlib's imshow, but I need an array of rgb values to use that, and I didn't like my method of converting a dataframe of 0-1 values to an array of [r,g,b] values. I think there's a better way of doing it than a nested loop- I just don't know what that is.

Comment: @Nathan The seaborn heatmap worked really well, though it took me a couple days to get nearly identical results to my original, more complex code. It definitely had me wondering why the coder who wrote the package I based my original code on didn't use it. I'm still curious as to how I could perform functions on elements of a dataframe to produce an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do, I'm sure it can be improved:

```
# reference image
img1 = np.zeros((*df.shape, 3))
img1[...,0] = df.mul(2).clip(upper=1)
img1[...,1] = df.mul(-2).add(2).clip(upper=1)

# notna values
notnull = df.notnull()

# select the correct colors
ret = np.select( (df.columns.isin(column_list_1)[:,None] & notnull, notnull),
                 (img1, img1[...,[1,0,2]]), (0,0,0))
```

Output (I'm not sure why the colors are a little different :-) )

[image]